# I am trying to create a loop so that while y is smaller than x it will loop through print statements while alternating through them

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

[my code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmC0B.png)

I am trying to make a program that will create a randomized password. Along with that, it is supposed to alternate between

```
print(chr(letter), end="")
print(chr(number), end="")
```

as it makes it so that the password looks something like "A2h8l" where it alternates between numbers and letters.

```
import random

number = random.randint(48,57)
letter = random.randint(65,122)

print(input("How many characters do you want in your password?"))

x = input

y = int(letter + number)

while int(x > y):
    print(chr(letter), end="")
    print(chr(number), end="")
```

For some reason, however,

```
while int(x > y):
```

shows up with an error, and I'm not sure what to do about it. No clue what I'm doing or doing wrong, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you think you've set `x` equal to? Have you tried, say, `print(x)` to check what's going on? (Also, please don't include images of text. You've already included your code here, which is good—just do the same for the error.)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, ill make sure to fix that if I have another question, but I thought I included the error in the image; unless I'm misunderstanding you, in which case sorry about that. @CrazyChucky

Comment: What I'm saying is that images of text aren't suitable at all, when the content could just be text. It would be better if you pasted the error into your question, formatted it as code, and removed the image. For more info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I believe I set "x" to be the user input, which would be an integer like 5 for example. What I was trying to go for was that the user would input "5" as the number of characters they wanted in their password and then "y" which was the letter and number added up would continue alternating and adding up while looping until the number of characters created by "y" equaled the integer in "x" which was provided by the user were equal. Sorry if my explanation of what I'm going for is confusing. @CrazyChucky

Comment: Thank you for the clarification regarding the image, I'll make sure to remember that next time I have a question. :) @CrazyChucky

Comment: I see what you're going for, and I apologize that apparently I was unclear. I'm suggesting how you could start investigating and troubleshooting your problem. If something isn't behaving the way you expect, try using `print` statements to verify that variables are set to the things you think they're set to. In this case, `x` is now a reference to the `input` function, not the value the user entered.

Comment: So how would I go about making "x" a reference to the value the user entered instead of referencing the "input" function? @CrazyChucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int(1 > 2)` is syntactically incorrect.

You cannot pass a comparison like this to the `int()` function. The correct way to do this would be

```
if int(1) > int(2):
```

Although, you still do not need the `int()` if you are passing an integer to begin with.

---

Even when resolving this issue your code continues to have problems.

Your loop will run indefinitely or not at all, dependant on the values of `x` and `y`, and will also print the same two chars constantly.

---

A better way to handle this is to:

1. Define password length
2. Loop over `range(length)`
3. Generate random integers and append them to a string

---

```
import random
length = int(input('Password Length'))
password = ''

for i in range(length):
    password = password + chr(random.randint(65,122)) + chr(random.randint(48,57))

password
#'Q5I4D8p8i9l1p7j0I6l9'
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code to try it out and for some reason, it doesn't work? Not sure if this affects the code majorly, but I'm using python 3.8 @PacketLoss

Comment: What does not work?  Change `password` on the last line to `print(password)` if you're running as a file

Comment: Thank you for that, it looks like that fixed it. @PacketLoss

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're running into that specific error is that you are setting x to the input function itself. Something like this would be closer to what you want:
`x = int(input("How many characters do you want in your password?"))`

Comment: I just tried it out, and all it does is print "How many characters do you want in your password" while asking for user input again. @eriblexp

Comment: Well that line would replace these current lines to prevent the error
`print(input("How many characters do you want in your password?"))

x = input`. Currently x is literally being set to the input function rather than being set to the text that is input in the console. You will still have a separate issue of the y value almost always being larger than x, but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: (your code get error just because `x=input`, so x is a function which can not be compare with int type)

```py
import random

x = int(input("How many characters do you want in your password? ").strip())

count = 0

while x > count:
    number = random.randint(ord("0"), ord("9"))
    upper = random.randint(ord("A"), ord("Z"))
    lower = random.randint(ord("a"), ord("z"))
    y = random.choice([number, upper, lower])
    print(chr(y), end="")
    count += 1
print()
```

Or more pythonic

```py
import random
import string

CHARS = string.digits + string.ascii_letters

x = int(input("How many characters do you want in your password? ").strip())
print(''.join(random.choice(CHARS) for _ in range(x)))
```

Comment: @PacketLoss get it, and changed

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could do something like this

```py
import random

number = random.randint(48,57)
letter = random.randint(65,122)

x = input("How many characters do you want in your password?")
x = int(x)
y = letter + number

while x > y:
    print(chr(letter), end="")
    print(chr(number), end="")
```

Comment: This will either print nothing, or keep printing the same two characters indefinitely.